# Jquery dataTables serverSide in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I tried this but i still need to fix my controller i think

I need to get the data from my database to the datatable

this is my table and my js

```
   <table id="myTable" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
         <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Status</th>
                   <th>Date and Time</th>
                   <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>                                           
   </table>
```

my Js

```
    <!--Import jQuery before export.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


<!--Data Table-->
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table buttons-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table button CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Profile/Index/viewModel/EmployeeCollection/HistoryOfStatuses",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CheckStatus", "name": "Status" },
                { "data": "CheckTime", "name": "Date and Time" }
            ],
            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "asc"],

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'print', 'excel'
            ]
        });
    });
```

My Controller looks like this In this datatable i need to use the HistoryOfStatuses

```
     public IActionResult Index(int? Id)
    {
        using (var context = new RSAT.Api.Data.Proxy.ATT2018NOVUSContext())
        {
            var baseViewModel = base.GetLayoutViewModel();
            var viewModel = new HomeViewModel()
            {
                User = baseViewModel.User,
                RoleCollection = baseViewModel.RoleCollection,
                TableCollection = baseViewModel.TableCollection,
                //Olap = baseViewModel.Olap,
                //Localization = baseViewModel.Localization,
                EmployeeCollection = (from userinfo in context.Userinfo
                                      where userinfo.Userid == Id
                                      join department in context.Dept on userinfo.Deptid equals department.Deptid
                                      select new Employee()
                                      {
                                          Id = userinfo.Userid,
                                          Name = userinfo.Name,
                                          Picture = userinfo.Picture,
                                          Department = department.DeptName,
                                          CardNumber = userinfo.CardNum,
                                          Status = userinfo.UserFlag.ToString(),
                                          ActualCheckinStatuse = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                                                                  join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                                                                  where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                                                                  orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                                                                  select new Checkinout
                                                                  {
                                                                      CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                                                                      CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                                                                  }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                          HistoryOfStatuses = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                                                               join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                                                               where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                                                               orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                                                               select new Checkinout
                                                               {
                                                                   CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                                                                   CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                                                               }).ToList(),

                                          TodayCheckedStatus = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                                                                join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                                                                where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                                                                where checkinout.CheckTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date
                                                                orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                                                                select new Checkinout
                                                                {
                                                                    CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                                                                    CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                                                                }).ToList()

                                      }).ToList()
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

And this is my class employee Controller that im going to use.

```
   public class Employee : BaseEntity
{        
    public Employee()
    {
        this.HistoryOfStatuses = new List<Checkinout>();
        this.TodayCheckedStatus = new List<Checkinout>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public Checkinout ActualCheckinStatuse { get; set; }
    public List<Checkinout> HistoryOfStatuses { get; set; }
    public List<Checkinout> TodayCheckedStatus { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; internal set; }

    public string UName { get; set; }
    public string UField { get; set; }

    public string UDeg { get; set; }
    //test
}
```

I need to use the datatable to sort and to download data in pdf and exel.

Comment: hi..are you sure to retunr View(viewModel) ? .. not a Jsonresult(viewModel) instead?

Comment: Your AJAX URL seem to be wrong here. Also no need to return all instances of viewmodel, because you have only 2 columns in datatable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how i fix it My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public string GetData()
    {
        string sJSONResponse = "";
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        using (var context = new RSAT.Api.Data.Proxy.ATT2018NOVUSContext())
        {
            var baseViewModel = (from userinfo in context.Userinfo
                                 join department in context.Dept on userinfo.Deptid equals department.Deptid
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Id = userinfo.Userid,
                                     Name = userinfo.Name,
                                     Department = department.DeptName,
                                     CardNumber = userinfo.CardNum,
                                     Status = userinfo.UserFlag.ToString(),
                                     HistoryOfStatuses = (from checkinout in context.Checkinout
                                                          join status in context.Status on checkinout.CheckType equals status.Statusid
                                                          where checkinout.Userid == userinfo.Userid
                                                          orderby checkinout.CheckTime descending
                                                          select new Checkinout
                                                          {
                                                              CheckStatus = status.StatusText,
                                                              CheckTime = checkinout.CheckTime
                                                          }).ToList(),
                                 }).ToList();

            foreach (var i in baseViewModel)
            {
                foreach (var h in i.HistoryOfStatuses)
                {
                    var s = "[\"" + h.CheckStatus + "\"," + "\"" + h.CheckTime + "\"]";
                    data.Add(s);
                }
            }

            string dataRez = "[";
            foreach (var i in data)
            {
                dataRez += i + ",";
            }
            dataRez = dataRez.Remove(dataRez.Length - 1);
            dataRez = dataRez + "]";
            sJSONResponse = "{\"draw\": 1,\"recordsTotal\": 57,\"recordsFiltered\": 57,\"data\":" + dataRez + "}";
        }
        return sJSONResponse;
    }
```

And my Script

```
   <!--Import jQuery before export.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


<!--Data Table-->
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table buttons-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!--Export table button CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $('#myTable1').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Profile/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "application/json"
            },

            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "asc"],
            "processing": "true",


            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'pdf', 'csv', 'print', 'excel'
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying status list in datatable, but you are returning the employee `viewModel`, I think you need to check your code and return proper data. Like below code

```
return Json(new
        {
            draw = model.draw,
            recordsTotal = viewModel.HistoryOfStatuses.Count(),
            recordsFiltered = viewModel.HistoryOfStatuses.Count(),
            data = viewModel.HistoryOfStatuses 
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You can check the link [Sample implementation of serverside processing in C# MVC](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)